# Upload blob file to wordpress with media_handle_upload

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, cordova

I'm sending a file by my cordova app and send a blob object
When I get it with server side, I try to upload it via `media_handle_upload` function but I can't this error :

> sorry this file type is not permitted for security reasons

I think wordpress doesn't allo blob object, but how to convert this object to upload my file with `media_handle_upload` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I proceeded another way

When I receive my blob file in php, I use this to upload the file in a temporary directory :

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destination);
```

Then I download the file (with url) with wordpress like that :

```
$file = array();
$file['name'] =basename($temp_url);
$file['tmp_name'] = download_url($temp_url);
```

Then I upload the file into wordpress as attachment with :

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_sideload($file, $post_id);
```

Don't forget to delete the temporary file with : `unlink($toDelete);` (path URL)

Comment: You moved temporary directory but in download_url you should paste url (nat path). How you get file url from temporary directory? Can you explain  $temp_url parameter?